# Can Bootstrap Modal be used without a Button? (jQuery Scroll Event)

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to use the Bootstrap modal as a popup that triggers on a jQuery scroll event. The scroll event works like so:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.Potato').css('top', jQuery('.Potato').closest('.post').height() + 'px');
    jQuery('#id-focus-comment').on('click', function(e) {
        jQuery('#comment').focus();
    });
    jQuery('.Potato').hide();
    jQuery(window).on('scroll', function(e) {
        if((jQuery('#reports').offset().top+jQuery('#reports').height()) < jQuery(window).height() + jQuery(window).scrollTop()) {
            jQuery('.Potato').show();
        }
    });
});
```

The script grabs the div hides/shows ''potato'' once a user has scrolled passed the ''reports'' section.

Another part of my script dynamically adds in the modal along with user generated content:

```
<div class="question">
  <div class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
          </button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Potato Counter</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>' + e.data.title + '</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But when it actually all triggers on the site, it looks nothing like a bootstrap Modal:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnqKT.png

I figure I must be missing something obvious? My dev console shows no errors loading any resources, and I see the bootstrap css and js files. Am I missing some required call/element that isn't triggering due to the lack of a button? (From what I understand that's normally how these are used?)

Comment: Forgot the modal class, look at the structure of the html http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals. Also, when a modal is triggered the body class is also changed to modal-open

Comment: Thanks - added in the modal fade. Rookie mistake! Not too sure what you mean about the second part though, changing the body class to modal-open; how might I go about that?

Comment: That body.modal-open happens when a modal is triggered, if you're triggering it some other way and you want it to have that dark background and the way it behaves, you'll have to add that class on load and remove it -- if it doesn't automatically get removed.

Answer (score 3):

Yes a bootstrap modal can be used without a button.

Please read up on the documentation here: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-usage

Based off your current HTML you could trigger the modal using:

```
jQuery('.question .modal').modal('show');
```